# Spacing/stretching marginnote

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, marginpar, marginnote

I want to do something like this

```
\marginnote{
\hspace{\stretch{1}}
\framebox{text}
\hspace{\stretch{1}}
}
```

i.e., center the marginnote. The problem seems to be that the width is defined to be that of `\textwidth`, so that the `\stretch` command assumes a margin width far larger than the actual 106pt. How can I redefine the width for `\stretch`?

Comment: assumes the marginnote package - i guess however it goes the same for \marginpar{}.

Comment: Without a minimal compilable example it's hard to test if it works, but I'd try and replace `\hspace{\stretch{1}}` with `\hss` (TeX command for horizontal stretch and shrink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
\marginnote{\makebox[120pt]{\fcolorbox{light2}{light}{asaddsdd}}}
```

with other words, you make a box with the correct margin width and the content will then center automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use `\raggedrightmarginnote` and `\raggedleftmarginnote`? See p. 3 of the [marginnote](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/marginnote.html) documentation for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\renewcommand*{\raggedrightmarginnote}{\centering}
% \renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{\centering}% for margin notes at the left margin

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

Some text.\marginnote{Some text inside a marginnote.} \blindtext

\end{document}
```